# How to create dynamic combination with php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 array like

```
$arr = [
  "color" => [["name"=>"red"]],
  "size" => [["name"=>"18 inch"], ["name"=>"15 inch"]],
  "type" => [["name"=>"plastic"]]
]
$combo = array();
    foreach ($arr['size'] as $size) {
        foreach($arr['color'] as $color){
           foreach ($arr['type'] as $type) {
               $variant =  json_encode(['size' => $size->name, 'color' => 
                                   $color->name, 'type' => $type->name]);
               array_push($combo,$variant);
           }
        }
    }
echo $combo;
```

// result

```
0 => "{"size":"15 inch","color":"yellow","type":"metal"}"
1 => "{"size":"18 inch","color":"yellow","type":"plastic"}"
```

It works properly but but there is can be less or more variants. How can I handle this.
For example

```
$arr = [
   "size" => [["name"=>"18 inch"], ["name"=>"15 inch"]],
   "type" => [["name"=>"plastic"]]
]
```

Or

```
 $arr = [
    "color" => [["name"=>"red"]],
    "size" => [["name"=>"18 inch"], ["name"=>"15 inch"]],
    "type" => [["name"=>"plastic"]],
    "brand" => [['name' => 'something']],
 ]
```

Comment: you can create two values for one index by something like this: `["name" => ["18 inch", "15 inch"]]` and you can't assign two values for a index...

Comment: BTW, your error reporting is disabled but you should be getting: `Trying to get property of non-object` when trying to access array properties as object.

Comment: I don't see how you get your result from your sample data...

Comment: Btw this is laravel collection. Main point $arr length can be different and have different keys

Comment: Is there any algorithm behind generating the expected array?

Comment: This is hard coded version. I need dynamic version generating this combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what i understand, you have to combine the arrays of properties into one array of 
object.

I have to leave now, but if you need a explanation leave a comment and i updated the answers

```
$arr = [
    "color" => [["name"=>"red"],['name'=>'yellow']],
    "size" => [["name"=>"18 inch"], ["name"=>"15 inch"]],
    "type" => [["name"=>"plastic"]],
    "brand" => [['name' => 'something']],
];

function runFor($arr ,&$array, $keys,$index,&$positions){
    foreach ($arr[$keys[$index]] as $key => $espec){
        $positions[$keys[$index]] = $key;
        if($index + 1 < count($keys)){
            runFor($arr,$array,$keys, $index+1,$positions);
        }else{
            $item = (object)[];
            foreach ($keys as $key){
                $item->$key = $arr[$key][$positions[$key]]['name'];
            }
            array_push($array,$item);
        }
        unset($positions[$keys[$index]]);
    }
}


$array = array();
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$positions = [];
runFor($arr,$array,$keys,0,$positions);
$combo = array();
foreach ($array as $item){
    array_push($combo,json_encode($item));
}
var_dump($combo);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I need every available combinations. For this case output will be
 0 => "{"color":"red","size":"18 inch","type":"plastic","brand":"something"}"
  1 => "{"size":"15 inch"}"

Comment: @AliagaAliyev - I updated my answer, now it should solve your problem. I had not understood your problem, my bad